# Why django doesn't generate a constraint for many-to-many mapping as follows:

Tags: django, django-models

**Question**> Why django 1.3 ('ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' ) doesn't apply constraint on the tag_id attribute of table bookmarks_tag_bookmark?

```
Generated:
    CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_tag_bookmarks" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "tag_id" integer NOT NULL,
        "bookmark_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_bookmark" ("id"),
        UNIQUE ("tag_id", "bookmark_id")
    )
    ;

Expected:
    CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_tag_bookmarks" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "tag_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_tag" ("id"),
        "bookmark_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_bookmark" ("id"),
        UNIQUE ("tag_id", "bookmark_id")
    )
    ;

    # ----- Detail of The Coding ------------ #
    user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Django/django_bookmarks$ cat bookmarks/models.py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    # Create your models here.

    class Link(models.Model):
        url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    class Bookmark(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
        link  = models.ForeignKey(Link)

    class Tag(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(Bookmark)

    user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Django/django_bookmarks$ python manage.py syncdb
    user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Django/django_bookmarks$ python manage.py sql bookmarks
    BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_link" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "url" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
    ;
    CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_bookmark" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "title" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
        "link_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_link" ("id")
    )
    ;
    CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_tag_bookmarks" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "tag_id" integer NOT NULL,
        "bookmark_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "bookmarks_bookmark" ("id"),
        UNIQUE ("tag_id", "bookmark_id")
    )
    ;
    CREATE TABLE "bookmarks_tag" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
    ;
    COMMIT;
    user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Django/django_bookmarks$
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `bookmarks_tag` is not created at that point, so it can't define the constraint at table creation time. However if you do `manage.py sqlall` you will see that it later does an `ALTER TABLE` to add the constraint once all the tables are created.

(Although it's worth pointing out that Sqlite ignores contraints except in very recent versions, and even then only if specifically enabled.)

Comment: I have tried your solution and my django with sqlite still doesn't print the expected result. --thx